# Using .location to add controls in C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, location, controls

So I have a problem with dynamically adding in a `textbox`, on button click, at a specific location. I've tried using `system.windows.forms` and `system.web.ui.webcontrols` namespaces however I still get `textbox1.location` underlined in red.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox textBox1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
    textBox1.Location = new Point(15, 15);
    this.Controls.Add(textBox1);
}
```

And if I use `system.windows.forms` for the declaration of my `textbox`, `this.Controls.Add(textBox1)` will be underlined red and it says cannot convert from windows forms to web controls.

Please help! I've researched everywhere but I cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: Why would you use Windows Forms namespace when you're dealing with an ASP.NET app? Do not do that! And in the web, you don't absolutely position controls like that. You use CSS and the HTML hierarchy to determine where something gets placed in the DOM. Sounds like you need to do some basic HTML and CSS learning.

Comment: Oh man i thought i could get away doing a webform without knowing html and css since there's the design view that allows me to add in controls. Anyway thanks man, yeah looks like ive got more researching to do !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the position of a control in ASP.NET. It isn't Windows Forms, which is for Desktop apps. ASP.NET ends up to be HTML and Javascript which need a little more work for you to get what you want.

If you want to set the control on a specific position, you have to append a class to it. Then style that class and determine its positioning using CSS.

Comment: Ahh i see, alright thanks! I will look more into css !